# AWS CDK how to build the container image on AWS (and not locally)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk

My problem: I'm using a Windows laptop and I'm hesitant to install Docker. I could use WSL/Ubuntu, but I don't want to build the the docker image locally. My broadband connectivity is also not the best. I rather want to build the docker image on AWS and upload it into ECR.

There are plenty CDK examples showing how to build the docker image **locally** (and upload to ECR), such as:

```
        docker_lambda = _lambda.DockerImageFunction(
            self, 'DockerLambda',
            code = _lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset('lambdas/docker_func'),
            timeout = Duration.seconds(30), # Default is only 3 seconds
            memory_size = 128,  # Small
        )
```

I'm aware of CDK Pipelines and for sure that will work. But it is also much more complicated.

I'm wondering if there is (DockerImageFunction?) an option that instead of building the Docker image locally, does the very same but on AWS?

Comment: I have this issue (limited/poor ADSL bandwidth) and the solution I came up with is to use Cloud9 and do all my docker builds that way - have you looked at this approach?

Comment: Either spin up an EC2 instance and perform the builds on that (which can be difficult to automate), or setup an AWS CodePipeline that uses a CodeBuild step to build the image and push it to ECR. Yes it is **much** more complicated, but those are your options.

Comment: Use CodeCatalyst and it will create an environment for you in your AWS account and manage the connectivity with VS Code locally for development.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the docker image on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu or whichever Linux you prefer and then push it to ECR with the help of the access key & secret key for an IAM user or assign an IAM role to the EC2 instance.

OR

You can configure a CodeBuild project with CodePipeline Setup and then push it to ECR.

Or you can use the Cloud9 IDE environment of AWS to do it.